# Script for old Backups in sqlserver2000

Tags: sql-server, scripting

Can anyone please send me the script to delete the old backup files greater than 2 days from the disk automatically? I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy if you create a [maintenance plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197136(SQL.80).aspx) to perform your backup.

One of the options is "[remove files older than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972273.aspx)". Here you can specify to delete the backups older than two days.